# Chisel synthesized none neither for verilog nor for C++

Tags: scala, hardware, digital-logic, chisel

For the following fragment Chisel synthesized none:

```
import Chisel._
import Node._
import scala.collection.mutable.HashMap

class PseudoLRU(val num_ways: Int) extends Module
{

    val num_levels = log2Up(num_ways)

    val io = new Bundle {
        val last_used_cline = UInt(INPUT,  width = num_levels)
        val update_state    = Bool(INPUT)
    }

    val state = Reg(Vec.fill(num_ways-1){Bool()})

    private val msb = num_levels - 1

    when (io.update_state) {

        // process level 0
        state(0) := !io.last_used_cline(msb, msb) // get the most significant bit

        // process other levels
        for (level <- 1 until num_levels) {
             val offset = UInt((1 << level) - 1, width = log2Up(num_ways-1))
             val bit_index = io.last_used_cline(msb, msb - level + 1) + offset
             val pos = msb - level
             val bit = io.last_used_cline(pos, pos)
             state(bit_index) := !bit
        }
    }
}

object test_driver {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val plru_inst  = () => Module(new PseudoLRU(num_ways = 16))
        chiselMain(args, plru_inst)

    }
}
```

The same behavior if manually unroll the loop for (level <- 1 until num_levels) and fold constants:

```
when (io.update_state) {
    state(                                            0  ) := !io.last_used_cline(3, 3)
    state( io.last_used_cline(3, 3) + UInt(1, width = 3) ) := !io.last_used_cline(2, 2)
    state( io.last_used_cline(3, 2) + UInt(3, width = 3) ) := !io.last_used_cline(1, 1)
    state( io.last_used_cline(3, 1) + UInt(7, width = 3) ) := !io.last_used_cline(0, 0)
}
```

The generated verilog (and similar C++ code) for both snippets (original and unrolled/instantiated for 16 ways case):

```
module PseudoLRU(input reset,
    input [3:0] io_last_used_cline,
    input  io_update_state
);

  wire T0;
  wire[151:0] T1;

  assign T0 = ! reset;
endmodule
```

Don't quite get why there are only dummy constructs
What should I do to enforce synthesis of the logic? Thanks!

Comment: What does `log2Up` mean in Chisel?

Comment: log2Up calculates the log (in base2) of a number, and rounds upwards to the nearest integer.  Very useful for calculating the number of bits required for an address.  Log2Up is a part of ChiselUtil.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chisel will aggressively prune signals in your design if they are not hooked up to anything.

It looks like in your case you have no OUTPUTS from PsuedoLRU, only inputs "last_used_cline" and "update_state".  It's just like writing a function in C/C++ and not doing anything with a function's results.

Now in C, you can tag the variable(s) as "volatile" to trick the compiler into keeping your code around (you're promising that somebody else is going to use the value of that variable).  In Chisel, you can use "debug()" to force signals to exist.

I believe to force your Vec of Regs to exist, you can do this:

```
for (i <- 0 until num_ways)
    debug(state(i))
```

Comment: After adding code for victimizing cache line and connecting to output wire the need for debug statement was fully eliminated.